# Unreal Engine 4.25.4 - CreateDefaultSubobject inside a child component attached to an actor loses values in blueprint editor

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I have the following actor:

```
UCLASS()
class X_API AMoveableRigidBodyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 

    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMoveableRigidBodyActor();

public: 

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditAnywhere, Category = "Custom")
        USceneComponent* SceneComponent;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditAnywhere, Category = "Custom")
        UMoveableRigidBodyComponent* MoveableRigidBodyComponent;

};
```

This Actor makes a reference to a `UMoveableRigidBodyComponent` and a `USceneComponent` which I run `CreateDefaultSubobject` on and attach in the following fashion in the constructor:

```
AMoveableRigidBodyActor::AMoveableRigidBodyActor()
{

    SceneComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(FName("AMoveableRigidBodyActor_SceneComponent"));
    SetRootComponent(SceneComponent);

    MoveableRigidBodyComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UMoveableRigidBodyComponent>(FName("AMoveableRigidBodyActor_MoveableRigidBodyComponent"));
    MoveableRigidBodyComponent->SetupAttachment(SceneComponent);

}
```

So far, so good.

Now inside my `UMoveableRigidBodyComponent` I instantiate a few components that are relevant to that component. I expect these components to be visible and manageable from within my blueprint:

```
UCLASS()
class X_API UMoveableRigidBodyComponent : public USceneComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 

    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UMoveableRigidBodyComponent();

override;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, EditAnywhere, Category = "Custom")
        USceneComponent* SceneComponent;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, EditAnywhere, Category = "Custom")
        UStaticMeshComponent* StaticMeshComponent;
        
};
```

Here I use CreateDefaultsuboject to attach everything to this component:

```
UMoveableRigidBodyComponent::UMoveableRigidBodyComponent()
{    
    SceneComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(FName("UMoveableRigidBodyComponent_SceneComponent"));
    SceneComponent->SetupAttachment(this);

    StaticMeshComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(FName("UMoveableRigidBodyComponent_StaticMeshComponent"));
    StaticMeshComponent->SetupAttachment(SceneComponent);
}
```

So, all of this feels pretty normal so far. So I go into my editor, create a blueprint that's based off of the `AMoveableRigidBodyActor` and I assign a static mesh to my component:

[image]

Still good. But then I hit the compile button:

[image]

The selected static mesh has now vanished from the editor but still seems to be filling the value correctly.

Furthermore, if I put this into the game world you can see that the static mesh sure enough isn't there in the instance:

[image]

What am I misunderstanding here?